# PHP include() Error

Tags: php, include

I am using include to attach a navbar and a footer to pages on my site. The navbar works perfectly but the footer keeps giving me this error:

`**Warning:** include(C:\inetpub\wwwrootooter.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\templatewip.php on line 69

**Warning:** include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\inetpub\wwwrootooter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\includes;C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\') in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\templatewip.php on line 69`

This is the code:

`<div id="footer">
<?php include("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\footer.php"); ?>
</div>`

If it helps, here is the working code for the navbar:

`<div class="navbar">
<?php include("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\menuembed.php"); ?>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\f` is the escape character for a form feed. So if you have `\f` in your string you need to escape the slash, too:

```
<div id="footer"> <?php include("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\\footer.php"); ?> </div>
```

Comment: Or use forward slashes `/`, which (surprisingly) works just as well on Windows.

Comment: The PHP engine will convert path seperators automatically so you are safe to use / even when on non-windows based platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you use backslashes in a string you risk bumping into escape sequences.

See here for details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Change your path to use forward slashes instead, and it will just work:

```
<?php include("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Include __DIR__.'footer.php';` if it is in your main dir, otherwise add path from your root dir to footer.php. For example my main folder is htpdocs and my footer is in inc folder then you write:

```
include __DIR__.'/inc/footer.php';
```

sorry for,mess writing from phone