# %%Include{ }%%Error accessing windows share through a Java application

Tags: java, php, php-include

I developed a Java application which gives access to shared folders from the Network.

**Scenario**
The application I am accessing includes a search field. I am accessing the file using the following code:

```
try {
    File file = new File("//192.x.x.x/asfa/ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2015 - Q1/cdrun.exe");
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to access Remote Database, Please try after some time!!!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also tried (only one of these lines at a time):

```
File file = new File("\\\\SERVER\\asfa\\ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2015 - Q1\\cdrun.exe");
File file = new File("\\\\192.x.x.x\\asfa\\ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2015 - Q1\\cdrun.exe");
File file = new File("//SERVER/asfa/ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2015 - Q1/cdrun.exe");
```

For all these above mentioned scenarios, the application `cdrun.exe` opens up(which is fine) from the `SERVER`, but gives an error message which is :
[image: error message]

So, from a few similar posts in SO[[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894621/php-include-error), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482253/php-include-file-showing-error-file-not-found)] and googling around, I found that **`%%Include{   }%%Error`** has something to do with your path specified. But I never came to a solution and the error continues to show up.

*Whereas when I access the application `cdrun.exe` from the `SERVER` itself, it runs fine*.

Any suggestions ?